# Should JSON-LD strings be escaped?

Tags: escaping, schema.org, json-ld

Should string values within JSON-LD content be escaped? For instance, Google recommends the following to provide hints for sitesearch:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "https://www.example-petstore.com/",
   "potentialAction": {
     "@type": "SearchAction",
     "target": "https://query.example-petstore.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
     "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
   }
}
</script>
```

But what if my site's search URL contains multiple query parameters? Should, or can, characters within the value for *target* be escaped? For instance:

```json
"target": "https://query.example-petstore.com/search?foo=bar\u0026q={search_term_string}",
```

The same question applies to several common schema.org types when marking up in JSON-LD. Google+ social profile links in Organization->sameAs for example: If my organization's profile is

```
https://plus.google.com/+BeardsAreSweet
```

should that be represented as:

```json
"sameAs": ["https://plus.google.com/+BeardsAreSweet"]
```

or

```json
"sameAs": ["https://plus.google.com/\u002bBeardsAreSweet"]
```

More importantly, does it matter at all?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to escape your url when it is part of a JSON object. A valid url string is a valid JSON string. A JSON String can contain:

> Any UNICODE character except \ or " or control character

http://json.org

Comment: What I'm primarily concerned with is not what is permitted in json, but how the string will be interpreted. For instance, in the "sameAs" example, would google interpret both strings equally? They both represent the same value when decoded, but are they decoded prior to evaluation? I didn't see anything in the spec about that.

Comment: The question is sill not answered! I also want to know: when a parameter in LD-JSON should have the value `https://example.com/search?q=abc&filter=true`, is it OK when I use the escaped version `https://example.com/search?q=abc&amp;filter=true` ??? Please help

Answer (score 0):

In my experience RTL characters (in particular, Persian letters in querystrings) can be problematic for Google, so they have to be encoded in an LD+JSON that is meant to be digested by Google.

CJK characters are fine, if left unencoded.